# en bord de mer, au bord de la mer, le bord de mer

Tags: vocabulaire

Est-ce qu’on peut utiliser les deux expression de manière interchangeable ou est-ce qu’il y a des expression où l’une est mieux que l’autre ?

On peut dire « le bord de mer » mais y a-t-il aussi « le bord de la mer » ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*en bord de mer*" au "*au bord de la mer*" sont parfaitement interchangeables.

"*le bord de mer*" et "*le bord de la mer*" se disent aussi tous les deux (même si *le bord de mer* me semble le plus naturel des deux)

En revanche l'article est obligatoire si l'on parle d'une mer en particulier :

> Le bord de **la** mer méditerranée

Comment: *Parfaitement interchangeables* du point de vue de la compréhension, d'accord mais pas dans l'usage. Je ne me vois pas dire *On est allé en bord de mer*, ce sera toujours pour moi *On est allé au bord de la mer*.

Comment: Pour moi il y a une notion de proximité qui distingue les usages.
À 1kilomètre du rivage je suis en bord de mer, à 10m de l'eau je suis au bord de la mer.

Comment: Si je vais passer mes vacances quelque part, ça serait plutôt au bord de la mer.

Answer (score 3):

D'après une recherche rapide sur Internet je crois que les deux locutions

> en bord de mer et au bord de la mer

sont équivalentes. Quand même il y a une nuance entre elles. La première est plus générique  et fait penser aux agences immobilières: "appartement à vendre en bord de mer". La seconde est plus courante.

Voir

https://www.francaisfacile.com/forum/lire.php?num=7&msg=58673&titre=Au+bord+-+en+bord

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/bord-de-la-mer-bord-de-mer.1462387/

https://www.maxicours.com/se/cours/au-bord-de-la-mer/

**EDIT**

Comme @jlliagre commente: Les deux locutions sont parfaitement interchangeables du point de vue de la compréhension, mais pas dans l'usage. On ne dit pas

- On est allé en bord de mer,
  mais plutôt
- On est allé au bord de la mer.

Pour faire encore une citation de @jlliagre

> Il y a aussi des différences liées à l'époque et probablement régionales dans l'usage. Les liens que tu as fourni montrent des opinions parfois contradictoires. Pour moi, les deux ne sont pas facilement interchangeables. En bord de mer n'a vraiment commencé être employé qu'après la deuxième guerre mondiale et a gagné beaucoup en popularité depuis une vingtaine d'années alors que au bord de la mer est beaucoup plus ancien.

Aussi

> Je trouve la locution avec en inusitée. Dans mon monde, si quelqu'un dit ça et a un accent anglais alors je le comprends comme un genre de calque de on, autrement je le perçois comme littéraire ou indiquant un locuteur d'une autre région que la mienne. (merci @némésie-t-île)

Comment: +1 pour la nuance. Il y a aussi des différences liées à l'époque et probablement régionales dans l'usage. Les liens que tu as fourni montrent des opinions parfois contradictoires. Pour moi, les deux ne sont pas facilement interchangeables. *En bord de mer* n'a vraiment commencé être employé qu'après la deuxième guerre mondiale et a gagné beaucoup en popularité depuis une vingtaine d'années alors que *au bord de la mer* est beaucoup plus ancien.

Comment: Je trouve la locution avec _en_ inusitée. Dans mon monde, si quelqu'un dit ça et a un accent anglais alors je le comprends comme un genre de calque de _on_, autrement je le perçois comme littéraire ou indiquant un locuteur d'une autre région que la mienne.